# How can artists make money when their albums and videos are free on YouTube?

Tags: music-video

Remember, Thriller made by **MJ**, he never released for free. still It is in Guinness world records for Highest selling album.

Music rappers like Taylor swift, Justin Bieber etc, releasing their albums for free in youtube under **VEVO** channel. then how can they earn money, then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Some youtube channels (VEVO included) may pay copyright holders a fee, which is a share of revenue through advertising on youtube.
2. Some artists intentionally release music/videos for free, actively promoting their shows and earning money on tickets and merhchandise.

Comment: Tim is correct, in the current music economy, musicians use the albums largely as an advertisement for the real money-makers, which are shows and merchandise.